# Need of having Caching in named servers

Tags: dns, bind

I am trying to understand why caching is required on the bind server, when the client receiving the responses would be caching based on TTL values.

So,
Is caching required on the server, if the client is not able to cache such responses? Isn't it a overhead on both the client and server systems to cache the same responses at respective ends
What are the possible Use cases of caching the responses at the Server?
What if there is a dynamic updates of Records on Server and Server still sends the cached Responses?

Comment: How did you even arrive at the conclusion that `named` is supposed/required to cache responses?

Comment: The TTL timers getting decremented when queried from a client, when the client was not caching responses. Every new query had TTL value lesser than the TTL value of the Zone. This could only mean the server was caching the Responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS requests **should** be cached at every single level.  If not, instead of hundreds of billions of DNS requests per day, we'd be dealing with quadrillions of them, over-clogging the DNS servers and probably slowing down every single connection on the Internet because of the traffic generated.

When your DNS server caches the request, it doesn't only cache it for a single computer.  It caches it for any other device you have that uses it too.

That principle distributes and greatly reduces the load on the rest of the world, and is applied recursively at multiple levels for those same reasons.